# Make a drive from one machine appear as a physical disk in another machine

Tags: storage, network-attached-storage, physical-to-virtual, hard-drive

I want to take a physical disk (or part of a disk) from one machine, call it **machine-A**, and make it available to another machine, **machine-B**. But *I don't want to map* a network drive. I want it to appear to **machine-B** as a *physical* drive. Even though it is not a physical drive.

I want to do this in order to create shares on **machine-B** on that drive. Since I cannot do that on mapped drives, I need to use a utility that fools **machine-B** into thinking that it is a physical drive, and treats it as such.

Both of machines are Windows Server 2003.

I heard about NFS ([Allegro NFS for Windows](http://www.nfsforwindows.com/home)). It sounds like it could be the solution to my problem.  Does it use a Linux/Unix protocol?  What tools can I use?  Are there open source solutions?

I don't care what the solution is, as long as I achieve my goal. I really would prefer an open source solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does the drive on machine-a still need to be available on machine-a?  If not you could serve it via iscsi from machine-a.  Using an iscsi client on machine-b you will have the ability to share out folders.  Here is an [article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5888332.html) that describes one option to make windows 2003 a iscsi target.

Comment: For a 1:1 link you can even use the free versions of most popular iSCSI Target servers.

Comment: @zoredache , it would be an added benefit if the drive could be available on machine-a.   But i'll dig a bit more on this iscsi subject and see if it could work for me.  Thank you.  I'm still open to any other ideas as well.

Comment: I have created a config which uses iSCSI and leaves the drive visible and usable on the host but it caused a bunch of problems as each machine believes it has exclusive access to the drive and acts accordingly.